# Pandas: How to replace an int substring with another value

Tags: python, arrays, regex, pandas, replace

I'd like to reduce the first integer in a string by 1

I have the following dataframe:

```
No              pl.     Expected              
B2bb-hb        0.56     0.35      
F378cq-h1      0.21     0.62   
W30mm2-fpr2    8.17     0.76    
Z51mm1-yu2     2.81     0.91
```

I'd like the output to be:

```
No              pl.     Expected              
B1bb-hb        0.56     0.35      
F377cq-h1      0.21     0.62   
W29mm2-fpr2    8.17     0.76    
Z50mm1-yu2     2.81     0.91
```

I tried the following code:

```
df['No'] = df['No'].str.replace('(\d+)','(\d+)-int(1)')
```

But I ended up with:

```
No                       pl.     Expected              
B(\d+)-int(1)b-h         0.56     0.35      
F(\d+)-int(1)cq-h1       0.21     0.62   
W(\d+)-int(1)mm2-fpr2    8.17     0.76    
Z(\d+)-int(1)mm1-yu2     2.81     0.91
```

Please how can I edit the code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way using `pandas.Series.str.replace` with `lambda` and `n`:

```
df["No"].str.replace("(\d+)", lambda x: str(int(x.group(1))-1), n=1)
```

Output:

```
0        B1bb-hb
1      F377cq-h1
2    W29mm2-fpr2
3     Z50mm1-yu2
Name: No, dtype: object
```

Comment: h1 change to h0

Comment: @Chris thanks for your answer, it worked! Could you please explain what group(1) does, and why you needed n=1? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @cave In the regex capture group `(\d+)`, the first group is the matching digits. The `lambda` operation then uses the first groups (`30`, `2`, `2` for row 2) and do the operation (i.e. convert them into `int` and subtract 1). `n` argument is used to limit this operation to be done only once, so that only the first numbers are subtracted, and rest remain the same.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for your explanation! One more question, what does (30,2,2) represent in the first group?

Comment: @cave The digits ;) W**30**mm**2**-fpr**2**

Comment: @Chris. Hi there, I have an off-topic request to ask. I just posted a new question that I've found difficult to solve. I'd really appreciate your help. Here is the link: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68469939/how-to-map-values-of-a-data-frame-to-the-row-and-column-header-of-another-data-f). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

We can try using `str.replace` here with a lambda function:

```py
repl = lambda m: m.group(1) + str(int(m.group(2)) - 1) + m.group(3)
df['No'] = df['No'].str.replace(r'^([^\W\d]*?)(\d+)(\w*)\b', repl)
```