# How to get the row-column name of a value from another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Given a table of ranges `(start, end)`:

```
name     blue         green          yellow        purple              
a        1, 5                        654, 678       11, 15
b                     88761, 88776  
c        1211, 1215                  38, 47    
d        89, 95                                     1567, 1578
```

And a data frame `df`:

```
Supplier        colour                   
Abi             1                               
John            678          
Smith           120               
Tim             1570 
Don             87560
```

How can I filter the `df` to contain only rows whose values in the `colour` column are within the ranges provided in the table?

And also create a third column that correlates the value in column `colour` to the `row-column` name from the table of ranges. I'd like the final `df` to look like this:

```
Supplier        colour    Source                  
Abi             1         a-blue                      
John            678       a-yellow                   
Tim             1570      d-purple
```

Thank you!

```
s = df2.stack()
print(s)
```

Gives:

```
a  1,      name          5
           blue       654,
           green       678
           yellow      11,
           purple       15
b  88761,  name      88776
c  1211,   name       1215
           blue        38,
           green        47
d  89,     name         95
           blue      1567,
           green      1578
dtype: object
```

And:

```
s = df2.stack()
s = s.str.split("[, ]+").apply(lambda x: pd.Interval(*map(int, x), closed="both"))
print(s)
```

Gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/sup.py", line 12, in <module>
    s = s.str.split("[, ]+").apply(lambda x: pd.Interval(*map(int,x), closed="both"))
  File "/Users/.conda/envs/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 4200, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 2402, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/sup.py", line 12, in <lambda>
    s = s.str.split("[, ]+").apply(lambda x: pd.Interval(*map(int,x), closed="both"))
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly replace `' '` to `NaN` via `replace()` method:

```
df1=df1.replace(r'\s+',float('NaN'),regex=True)
                  #^ it will replace one or more occurence of ' '
```

Then The idea is to make the string ranges to actual list of combined range values:

```
s=df1.set_index('name').stack().dropna().replace('',float('NaN')) 
#OR if the above line not working them try: 
#s=df1.set_index('name').stack().dropna().replace('',float('NaN'),regex=True) 
m=s.str.split(',').map(lambda x:range(int(x[0]),int(x[1])+1)).explode()
s=m.unique()
m.index=m.index.get_level_values(0)+'-'+m.index.get_level_values(1)
m=m.drop_duplicates()
```

Finally:

```
out=df2[df2['colour'].isin(s)]
#Filtered out the data
```

Now create Source column:

```
out['Source']=m[m.isin(out['colour'].tolist())].index
```

OR

```
out['Source']=out['colour'].map(dict(m.reset_index()[[0,'index']].values))
```

output of out:

```
   Supplier     colour  source
0   Abi         1       a-blue
1   John        678     a-yellow
3   Tim         1570    d-purple
```

Comment: I didn't get the correct values for ```678``` and ```1570```. I got ```a-blue``` for 678, instead of ```a-yellow```, and I got ```a-green``` for  ```1570```, instead of ```d-purple```

Comment: @cave It is working fine on my side....updated answer kindly have a look...now see if it works or not **:)**

Comment: @cave so this solution is not working for you right?

Comment: No, it didn't work. I got ```m=s.str.split(',').map(lambda x:range(int(x[0]),int(x[1])+1)).explode()```
```ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''```

Comment: @cave updated answer...kindly have a look and let me know if you further face any problem **:)**

Comment: I got ```AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!```

Comment: @cave on which line of code do you get this error?

Comment: When I read the csv files as ```sep ='\t'```. I got this error: ```AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!```. And when I read the csv files as ```delim_whitespace='True'```. I got this error: ```m=s.str.split(',').map(lambda x:range(int(x[0]),int(x[1])+1)).explode()```
```ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''```

Comment: @cave I think the problem is with your csv file as for the given data it is working

Comment: My original file is an excel file, not a csv file. And there's nothing wrong with it. I think the error stems from this line: ```m=s.str.split(',').map(lambda x:range(int(x[0]),int(x[1])+1)).explode()```

Comment: If use the ```print(df1)``` statement after this line: ```df1=df1.replace(r'\s+',float('NaN'),regex=True).replace('',float('NaN'),regex=True)```. You will see that the entire cells are converted to ```NaN```. All the values are replaced by ```NaN```

Comment: @cave updated answer...kindly check **:)**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235168/discussion-between-cave-and-anurag-dabas).

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to make a `series` with `pd.IntervalIndex` :

```
s = df2.stack()
s = s.str.split("[, ]+").apply(lambda x: pd.Interval(*map(int, x), closed="both"))
s.index = ["-".join(i) for i in s.index]
s = pd.Series(s.index, index=s)
```

So that you have:

```
[1, 5]              a-blue
[654, 678]        a-yellow
[11, 15]          a-purple
[88761, 88776]     b-green
[1211, 1215]        c-blue
[38, 47]          c-yellow
[89, 95]            d-blue
[1567, 1578]      d-purple
dtype: object
```

Now you `map` it to original `df` and `dropna`:

```
df["Source"] = df["colour"].map(s)
df.dropna()
```

Output:

```
  Supplier  colour    Source
0      Abi       1    a-blue
1     John     678  a-yellow
3      Tim    1570  d-purple
```

Comment: I got an error: ```s = s.str.split("[, ]+").apply(lambda x: pd.Interval(*map(int, x), closed="both"))
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable```

Comment: @cave It looks like `df2.stack()` didn't remove the `nan`s, which it should have. Make sure you don't have `nan`s when you do `s.str.split`

Comment: So should I do ```s = s.dropna()``` in the line before ```s = s.str.split("[, ]+").apply(lambda x: pd.Interval(*map(int, x), closed="both"))```

Comment: Well `df2.stack()` already has `dropna` and it worked as expected on myside. Can you post the result of `df2`? Yes I'm referring to the table of ranges as `df2`

Comment: My IDE flagged ```closed="both"``` as an unexpected argument in ```s = s.str.split("[, ]+").apply(lambda x: pd.Interval(*map(int, x), closed="both"))```

Comment: @cave Can you post it into the question not comment?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235165/discussion-between-cave-and-chris).